# Having connections, user authentication in source code?

Tags: java, database, security

I'm working on a desktop app that talks with a database. I also want to implement user authentication. I can set all this up easily, but isn't it not secure just to have all that info in  the source code? I know it's not a web app but still, just want to make sure I'm doing it right. For example, you could connect like this:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("host","user", "password");
```

Would this be bad to have in your source code?

Comment: You need to give a more specific description of what you intend to do, otherwise nobody can answer this. One thing: if you connect to a database from a desktop application, you can expect that database to handle the authentication. You just need to ask the user for username/password and use those when you connect to the database.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I edited the question, is it a bad practice to have things like password or connection strings hard coded?

Comment: Cmon man, we get this question daily. Use search

Answer (score 1):

What I have used in my applications is a salted password. Passing a salted password is a lot more secure! Since there is no need to re-invent the wheel, [Here](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm#javasourcecode) is some source code to salt passwords that you can integrate into your program.

Comment: Thank you so much @Frank! I will def give this a shot!